# How to be notified in some way (push notification, alarm/sound) when step counter sensor reaches a certain number of steps?

Tags: android, kotlin

I've created a step counter in Android (Kotlin) which all works fine - I'm pretty new to android programming...
Anyway, what I need is, to be notified in some way when the count reaches a certain number.
This is easy when the app is open/in foreground.
What if the app is backgrounded?
Appreciate any ideas.

I really don't know what to do here or what to research

Comment: You can create a background service and move the logic related to setp counter to background service or workmanager. https://developer.android.com/guide/background

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply - I actually figured it out and it's a 'foreground service'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).